# Doing line integral without parametrizing

Tags: integration, vectors, line-integrals

We have to evaluate  integral

$$ \int_c \vec{f(r}) . d\vec{r}$$

where c is the circle of radius b originated in the countercheck wise direction.

Let's define two functions.

$$1. \ \  \vec{f(r)} = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j}$$
$$2. \ \ \vec{f(r)} = - y \hat{i} + x \hat{j}$$

I have the solution of this two questions. The author says that the direction  of the position vector of the first one is always perpendicular to the tangential direction and therefore we don't need to parametrize to find out the integral. And it is zero. On the other hand, the angle is $0^0.$ I don't understand how the angle works in this case.  Could you please explain the cenerio?

Comment: (1) Your "two functions" are the same.  Is that intentional?  (2) If by "the angle" you mean the angle between the vector field at a given point on the curve and the tangential direction along the curve at that same point, then no it is not $0^\circ$.  It's $90^\circ$ which is why you can immediately say that the line integral is zero.

Comment: Sorry i have edited the second function.